# Docker - mysql configured with empty password for the root user

Tags: spring-boot, docker, mysql-8.0

I am new to docker and try to run a mysql image using below command on a windows server.

```
docker run  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=sEe@21 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=emp_db -p 3306:3306 --name mysql_emp mysql
```

It successfully downloaded and configured. I am getting a log in the CMD which says

```
root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
```

I have already given the root password which I set to use by the application and hence I get an error saying that cannot connect to DB from the spring boot service. MySQL full log is as follows

```
2021-02-10 14:25:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.
2021-02-10 14:25:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2021-02-10 14:25:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.
2021-02-10 14:25:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2021-02-10T14:25:43.801929Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) initializing of server in progress as process 43
2021-02-10T14:25:43.808218Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-02-10T14:25:44.547274Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-02-10T14:25:46.632843Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2021-02-10 14:25:51+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
2021-02-10 14:25:51+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
2021-02-10T14:25:51.770335Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) starting as process 88
2021-02-10T14:25:51.804446Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-02-10T14:25:52.039318Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-02-10T14:25:52.169969Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-02-10T14:25:52.299951Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-02-10T14:25:52.300259Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-02-10T14:25:52.304466Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2021-02-10T14:25:52.327240Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.23'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2021-02-10 14:25:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
2021-02-10 14:25:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database emp_db

2021-02-10 14:25:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
2021-02-10T14:25:58.448858Z 11 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user root. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.23).
2021-02-10T14:26:00.212816Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.23)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2021-02-10 14:26:00+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped

2021-02-10 14:26:00+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.

2021-02-10T14:26:00.738118Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) starting as process 1
2021-02-10T14:26:00.763121Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-02-10T14:26:00.999006Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-02-10T14:26:01.135971Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-02-10T14:26:01.269210Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-02-10T14:26:01.269444Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-02-10T14:26:01.275037Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2021-02-10T14:26:01.297388Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.23'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Would like to understand what is wrong I am doing ? any parameter is missing in the docker run command ?

Answer (score 13):

It is just an example of misleading printing:

> That is just a warning printed by during database file initialization (mysqld --initialize-insecure). The root user with password is created later while the database is listening only on the unix socket.

From https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/307#issuecomment-313784886

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you structure your run command as it is on the MySQL Docker hub page:

```
docker run --name mysql_emp -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=sEe@21 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=emp_db -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:latest
```

If that doesn't work you could try running from a dockerfile, similar to this question: [MYSQL docker file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42781733/mysql-docker-file/42802426)

Comment: It downloads a new image but doesn't run itseems. I am not seeing the log.                                                             Digest: sha256:b1cc887ed32cc6c2f217b12703bd05f503f2037892c8bb226047fe5dff85a109
Status: Downloaded newer image for mysql:latest
45283473c3c7b32b4e0ea4b5313b4155ea4dfb2ee78eae898c8a3821747dc92a

Comment: What entry I need to enter in my existing dockerfile to start a mysql?

Comment: Have you tried just going ahead with it anyway, I found this https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/307

Comment: yes the application is saying cannot connect to db.

Comment: Seems to be a strange issue. As you said I can login using root password given.  Even non-docker service can communicate to the dockerized mysql. I see some issue with the services. May be a docker-compose is required ?

Comment: @JAVA_CAT I think it's worth a shot, let me know how it turns out

Comment: You can update the flagged comment as the answer. By seeing that link only I thought of checking the other way which I mentioned above. I have another thread for tracking service issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66098814/docker-spring-boot-application-connectivity-with-mysql/66099408#66099408